How to handle unhealthy internal state in an AWS Lambda?
I'm working on my first AWS Lambda based application and I ran into a question I can't find the answer for anywhere.
According to the best practices on functions, you should set up database connections outside the function handler so they may be reused.  What happens if the connection becomes unhealthy in some unrecoverable way?  There is a long list of things that can happen to cause this from the connection failing, database location changing, or even just bugs in the driver itself.  It doesn't matter what the actual cause is.  There is a class of problems that are self-healing if this function is torn down and recreated, reestablishing the database connection.
What does lambda offer to deal with this?  Does AWS do any kind of anomaly detection on results and pull unhealthy functions out of rotation?  If so are there docs on this and what it looks for?  Is there an API for reporting errors from inside the function that can say "not only did I fail, but I may be in an unhealthy state and shouldn't get anymore traffic"?
I've been looking through docs and have found several places where they reference setting up this state shred state and holding the connection open, but I haven't found anything about how to handle when it fails.

The only way to force a cold start afaik is through a configuration change or code deployment to the Lambda function. You have complete control over your code, however, so you typically should be able to react to negative outcomes and clean up resources as needed. Bugs in an underlying library/driver do sound like a challenge, however. Ideally, your dependency would provide ways to deal with this (or you might have to raise a bug with them to provide such a thing for this environment).

Lambda doesn't change this problem - any long running application needs to handle the same thing.  The traditional way is with a connection pool that runs a small SQL script (i.e. select 1) when a connection is used to make sure it is valid.  Don't think like Microsoft - "when in doubt reboot".  Use tools that have existed for decades.

The concerns of 1). gracefully restoring connectivity between our data store's connection client inside our applications and 2). graceful transient error handling has always been an application-level concern.
However, different Lambda functions have different ways of reacting to failed executions (Not just related to clients) that occur inside them. This behaviour is mainly based on the invocation method used to trigger them.

For synchronous functions, Lambda won't attempt any retry and inform the invoking client about the failure.
For asynchronous functions, Lambda will retry function errors twice so better design your functions for idempotency.
Event source mapped functions, it differs on the source of the event.

